# Merging BufferedImages leaves black border

Tags: java, multithreading, bufferedimage

For a class project, we were required to take a program that implements the Sobel algorithm and run it across multiple threads as an exercise to become familiar with threading. I have the program running correctly as far as threads go (as far as I can tell), however whenever I implement it using more than 1 thread, I see a black border running down the dividing area where the buffer doesn't seem to be writing to the destination BufferedImage.

Here is some code of the method responsible for threading and writing the file:

```
public void processImage(int threads)
{
    try{
        File imgFile = new File(bmpFile);
        image = ImageIO.read(imgFile);

        w = image.getWidth();
        wThr = (image.getWidth()/threads);
        h = image.getHeight();
        inData = new int[wThr*h];
        BufferedImage[] pieces = new BufferedImage[threads];

        //instantiate array used for storing pieces of image
        for (int i=0; i<threads; i++){
            pieces[i] = new BufferedImage(wThr, h, BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY);
        }

        wThr = pieces[0].getWidth();
        h = pieces[0].getHeight();

        //instantiate target image
        combined = new BufferedImage(w, h, BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY);

        //split into threads, each one taking a division of the image and running algorithm
        Thread[] threadList = new Thread[threads];
        for (int i = 0; i < threadList.length; i++) {
            image.getRaster().getPixels((i*wThr), 0, wThr, h, inData);  
            threadList[i] = new Pr1();
            threadList[i].start();
            try{
                threadList[i].join();
            }catch (InterruptedException ie) {}

            //Write images to pieces and draw pieces individually onto target image
            pieces[i].getRaster().setPixels(0, 0, wThr, h, outData);

            Graphics2D g = combined.createGraphics();
            g.drawImage(pieces[i], i*(wThr), 0, null);
            g.dispose();

        }
            outFile = new File("1.bmp");
            ImageIO.write(combined, "BMP", outFile);
    }
    catch(IOException e)
        {
        // Handle the exception here!
        }
    }
```

This is the image when processed with 2 threads: https://i.stack.imgur.com/p3Tsx.png

Anyone have any insight on how to repair this? I've altered the parameters of the BufferedImages and arrays every way I can think and still no luck.

Comment: Wow! If that 275Kb image was 10% (or even 20%) of the size, I might have edited it directly into the question!  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  Either hot-link to a small (in bytes) image or generate one at run-time.

Comment: I wonder if the original image was 1001 pixels wide. You have integer division to compute `wThr` and don't account for remainder.

Comment: The original image is 1000x1000, so it shouldn't drop any pixels based on just a 2 thread example as far as I can tell since it would result in an even division. Is there some reason integer division would cause issues?

Comment: so how do you say it's multi-thread?!! you start a thread and attempt to join for it just after you start it!, so this is as same as a single thread. and maybe [this example](http://arashmd.blogspot.com/2013/07/java-thread-example.html#rccig) would help.